# Circle Tool for Paint in Python

Tags: python, int, pygame, paint, geometry

I am working on creating a paint program using python.  I am currently having difficulties with the circle tool.  Basically, I would like for the user to be able to create solid circles by dragging them out from a stationary point on the canvas just as in any paint program.  I am currently get this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Wisdom1\Desktop\Comp Science Files\Canvas.py", line 168, in
>   
>       draw.circle(screen,(c),(int(x),int(y)),(int(mx-x),int(my-y)),0) TypeError: an integer is required.

I am not sure if my code for the circle is exactly correct and if there is a more efficient way to complete this tool please let me know.  Any help with the error is greatly appreciated.  Here is my code:
`

```
`if mb[0] == 1 and canvas.collidepoint(mx,my):
 screen.set_clip(canvas)
 if tool == "ellipse":
     screen.blit(copy,(0,0))
     draw.circle(screen,(c),(int(x),int(y)),(int(mx-x),int(my-y)),0)
 screen.set_clip(None)
```

By the way, I also have the mouse position in my event loop.

Comment: Can you copy the exact text of the error message and edit it into your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments `draw.circle()` expects are:

```
circle(Surface, color, pos, radius, width=0)
```

Your `Surface`, `color`, `pos` and `width` arguments look OK, but for `radius` you have a two-element tuple: `(int(mx-x),int(my-y))`. What you want there is a single number representing the radius of the circle. I can't quite tell from your code what that radius should be, but you need to replace that tuple with a single value. To test it out, you could just hardcode it with a number like 20:

```
draw.circle(screen, c, (int(x), int(y)), 20, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  This helped me figure it out instantly!